# How to display Google maps in a view of an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, google-maps, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an application which calculates routes using `Google Maps API`. I want to display the map in a view of an `Eclipse RCP` perspective and not by creating a browser instance and displaying the whole browser in a view.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible. you might end up arranging/painting tile images on SWT canvas that you get from Maps API

Comment: @SambiReddy - Thanks! But the Maps API returns a JSON or XML file and not tiles. That is what is puzzling me.

Comment: @Rajath- Seems like google doesnt provide access to its tiles server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993981/how-to-access-google-maps-api-in-java-application

Comment: Another approach: As you don't have access to tile server, you will not be able to render them on Canvas. You can use browser and run google java script API to render maps in browser. (Look at  Browser.execute(String script) )

Comment: @sambireddy Thank you so much! It's starting to work. Sadly, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Does openstreetmap.org provide API or do I have to download the map tiles?

Comment: @Rajath: That's a different question.  I cannot give you a good answer in a comment.