# Tutorials for connecting Angular web service to Axon Server?

Tags: angular, axon

I'd like to deploy my UI from Angular, and the Angular server needs to connect with the Axon Server, putting commands on the command bus.

- Is there an API reference for Axon Server?
- Are there any tutorials out there describing how to make a call from javascript/Typescript to the command gateway?

To be clear, my communication path looks like this:

```
browser <--> web server (Angular) <--> Axon Server <--> backend services
                                   ^
                                   |
                                   this is where I'm needing help
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Close voter, I think this question falls within bounds, as it is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", per the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think this question is on par with other accepted questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993981/how-to-access-google-maps-api-in-java-application

Comment: And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511595/how-to-access-the-api-for-git-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some excellent feedback from Google groups for Axon Framework. I'm posting here to benefit anyone that stops by:

> On Friday, March 8, 2019 at 3:30:42 PM UTC-6, ben.r...@gmail.com
>   wrote:
>
> I believe your <-------h-e-l-p--n-e-e-d-e-d--h-e-r-e--------> is a
>   java based http api.  Something like spring boot using a RestAPI which
>   is responsible for producing the commands. handling the events, and
>   updating your projections. At this time, Axon Framework is only
>   available on the JVM.
>
> -Ben

And this one:

> On Monday, March 11, 2019 at 5:22:25 AM UTC-5, Steven van Beelen
>   wrote: Hi Jonathan, Ben,
>
> Ben's point is right, Axon Framework is only available on the JVM. The
>   Axon Server API however is gRPC based, and you could thus connect to
>   it in any language where you can use gRPC.
>
> By the way, the Axon Server API can be found [here](https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-server-api). I am currently not
>   aware of any tutorial showing you how to do this from
>   JavaScript/Angular; you'd be somewhat of a pioneer, afaik.
>
> That's my two cents.
>
> Cheers, Steven